# Actors disappear when layer changement LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx, layer, actor

My game is pretty well advanced but I'm facing a problem these days, that I don't manage to solve...
I have a maze and a character in it. For each row of the maze, I define a Group for the stage actors, and put in this Group every actor of the row (walls for example).
After that, I end with an array of Group `(Group[] layers)` whose size is equals to the number of rows in the maze, and put every Group in my stage.
Until this, it works perfectly, my walls are drawn, my character too, and his head appears behind the first row of walls, due to the layer.

But when my character changes row, I want to change his "layer", so its order in the stage.
My idea was to do :

`layers[previousRowOfTheCharacter].removeActor(this);
layers[newRowOfTheCharacter].addActor(this);`

And here is the problem...AddActor apparently removes the actor before adding it. The problem is that my character is never added in the stage, because he's not drawn.

To summarize quickly : 

`static Group[] layers = Group[numberOfRows];
Stage stage = new Stage();`

add all actors to be drawn to the layers through 

`layers[row].addActor(); (works)`

add all groups in the stage through 

`stage.addActor(group); (works)`

When a character changes row : 

`layers[previousRow].removeActor(this); 
layers[newRow].addActor(this);` (doesn't work, character disappear)

I can't use stage.addActor because it doesn't allow me to order the actors. I read it's possible through a Comparator, but it still seems to be a big mess. I tried it, and my current way seems clearer to me.

Does someone has a solution for this ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't understand why your setup isn't working but a workaround that I could suggest would be to use Z-index's of actors instead.

`Actors` in LibGDX have z-index's where a higher one is drawn on top of a lower one, you could use this by setting each `Group` to have a certain z-index based on which row it is and have the player `Actor` be by itself and have a z-index that corresponds to which row it is on.

Comment: From what I read, I understood that z-index doesn't really work because the stage seems to reset apparently the z-index...